# Python Vowel Remover

Tags: python

I wrote a program for Codecademy that removes the vowels from a string. It isn't working properly for some reason I can't figure out. Here is my code:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    wordcontents=list(text)
    vowel=['a','e','i','o','u']
    for letter in wordcontents:
        if letter in vowel:
            wordcontents.remove(letter)
    word=''
    word=word.join(wordcontents)
    return word

anti_vowel("Hey Look Words!")
```

with the result:

```
"Hy lk Words!"
```

Any insight? What is my mistake?

Comment: The problem is that you are iterating over a collection and removing things from it at the same time and that never goes well. Instead, create a new list as you iterate through the first.

Answer (score 2):

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowel= 'aeiou'
    return ''.join(c for c in text if c not in vowel)
```

Comment: To make this shorter: You never use `wordcontents` so you can delete the first line of the function  and you can use `vowel = 'aeiou'`. Last thing: you don't need a list as a parameter for `join`. Drop the square brackets and use the generator instead.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks, you are right. I copy pasted from the question. I didn't know it works without the square brackets. Learning something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

Alex Hall's comment is right.

What is happening is you are skipping over the second 'o' in 'Look' and then removing it when you find the one in 'Words'. The way you are iterating over the string while removing items is causing you to skip over letters and that doesn't matter until you reach two vowels in a row.

Put a print statement right after your for loop to see what I mean

```
print "checking " + letter + " in " + ''.join(wordcontents):
```

A better way to attack the problem would be to iterate through the vowel list and keep removing vowels from the string until that vowel does not appear in the string anymore.

remove traverses the list and removes the first instance of the provided object.

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 1].remove(1) #this removes just the first instance of 1
```

if you call remove(1) on the list again it will remove the last number.

and if you call it one more time it will throw an exception.

If you do something like this

```
while 'a' in wordcontents:
    wordcontents.remove('a')
```

It will keep calling the remove function until there are no more instances in the list.